# How to embed a video in angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, embed

I have angular 8 application and I can embed Youtube videos. But for example this url: https://vimeo.com/346340496/11432ab1db it will not work. So how can I get it working with also vimeo, or a generic solution. So that you can embed youtube, vimeo, other format...etc.

This is the code I have:

```
private getVideoSafeUrl(url: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    const embedUrl = this.parseYoutubeUrl(url);
    const safeUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      this.parseYoutubeUrl(embedUrl)
    );
    return safeUrl;
  }

  private parseYoutubeUrl(url: string): string {
    let returnUrl = url;
    const splitString = url.split('?');
    if (splitString.length > 1) {
      const baseUrl = splitString[0].replace('watch', 'embed');
      let videoId;
      const queryString = splitString[1];
      const newQueryString = queryString
        .split('&')
        .reduce((prev, cur) => {
          const entryArray = cur.split('=');
          if (entryArray[0] === 'v') {
            videoId = entryArray[1];
          } else {
            prev.push(cur);
          }
          return prev;
        }, [])
        .join('&');
      returnUrl = `${baseUrl}/${videoId}?${newQueryString}`;
    }
    if (url.indexOf('youtu.be') !== -1) {
      returnUrl = url.replace(/.*youtu\.be\/(.*)/g, (match, g1) => {
        return `https://youtube.com/embed/${g1}`;
      });
    }
    return returnUrl;
  }
```

and this is the template of it:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="is('VideoDisplay')">
          <iframe
            *ngIf="videoUrl.value"
            class="video-iframe"
            type="text/html"
            [src]="getVideoSafeUrl(videoUrl.value)"
            frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen
          ></iframe>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input
              matInput
              type="url"
              name="videoUrl"
              ngModel
              #videoUrl="ngModel"
              placeholder="Url of video"
              i18n-placeholder
              required
            />
            <mat-error>
              <app-element-edit-field-error
                [errors]="videoUrl.errors"
              ></app-element-edit-field-error>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </ng-container>
```

so my question is: how can I have it working with viemo, or a generic solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to extend function `getVideoSafeUrl` to include vimeo videos.

Consider this approach

```js
private getVideoSafeUrl(url: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    let safeUrl = '';

    if(this.isVimeoUrl(url)) {
      safeUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        this.parseVimeoUrl(url)
      );

      return safeUrl;
    }

    safeUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      this.parseYoutubeUrl(url)
    );
    return safeUrl;
  }
```

`isVimeoUrl` function checks whether url is from Vimeo.

`parseVimeoUrl` function would extract video_id from `https://vimeo.com/346340496/11432ab1db`.

In this case this value is `346340496`, and compute new url with structure `https://player.vimeo.com/video/{video_url}`

There is Vimeo developer site which explain things in detail.

[source](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos)

Example embed iframe

```html
 <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/346340496" width="320" height="200" frameborder="0" title="test" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look. I also found something like this: import { EmbedVideoService } from 'ngx-embed-video';

Comment: Well its up to you. Either create iframe by yourself and supply all necessary data or use 3rd party component/service and provide data there :)

Comment: Oke, but the function: isVimeoUrl will be like the function: parseYoutubeUrl  but then with vimeo?

Comment: `isVimeoUrl` would check if its valid url type then it subbranch to `parseVimeoUrl`

Comment: Oke, but how looks the function? isVimeoUrl

Comment: And I get this error: Type 'SafeResourceUrl' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Comment: So I have to make a copy of parseYoutubeUrl?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple method and parse the video URL be it of youtube and then can manipulate them using string methods.

I am adding the method below for your reference.

```
getTrustedVideoURL(videoURL: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    let srclink = videoURL;

    if (srclink.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=')) {

      let embedlink = srclink.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/')
      return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(embedlink);

    } else if (srclink.startsWith('https://youtu.be')) {

      let embedlink = srclink.replace('https://youtu.be', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/')
      return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(embedlink);

    } 
    else {

      return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(srclink);

    }
  }
```

Hope this solved your query of having a generic solution.